# Como somar os resultados de um array trazido do banco de dados em PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, array

Estou fazendo isso, mas o que está sendo somado é o número de linhas e não os valores do campo "algo".

```
<?php 
$searc= mysql_query ("SELECT algo FROM lugar")  or die (mysql_error());

while ($rows = mysql_fetch_array($searc)) {
$soma_das_visu = array_sum($rows); 
}
?>
```

Comment: Tente somar os valores da chave certa:
`$total= 0;
while(....){
$total += $rows['valor']`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Você pode lidar com isso direto da sua query

```
SELECT SUM(nome_coluna) AS valor_soma FROM nome_tabela;
```

Você pode até somar outras colunas...

```
SELECT SUM(nome_coluna1 + nome_coluna2) AS valor_total_soma FROM nome_tabela;
```

No php tente algo como:

```
$result = mysql_query('SELECT SUM(nome_coluna1) AS valor_soma FROM nome_tabela'); 
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result); 
$sum = $row['valor_soma '];
```

Comment: Grato, não encontrava na mente nenhuma opção: agora tenho duas. Vou usar diretamente do query. It's done!

Comment: Bacana! Bom ter ajudado.

Answer (score 3):

O array_sum não funciona conforme o esperado pq `mysql_query()` retorna apenas uma linha e não o array inteiro, por exemplo:

```
SELECT valor FROM tabela
```

será retornado a *linha*:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 150
    [valor] => 150
)
```

Quando aplicado o array_sum o resultado será 300 pois está somando o valor das duas chaves e também pq `$soma_das_visu` é sobrescrita a cada volta do while.

Dependendo de como está a sua consulta a resposta do @Leandro Curioso é a mais prática. Ou vc pode utilizar uma variável para guardar o total:

```
$total = 0;
while ($rows = mysql_fetch_array($searc)) {
   $total += $rows['valor']; 
}
 echo 'total: '+ total;
```

Comment: Vou usar o exemplo do Curioso mesmo, grato.

Answer (score 2):

Coloque o respectivo campo `'algo'`:

```
<?php 
$searc= mysql_query ("SELECT algo FROM lugar")  or die (mysql_error());

$soma_das_visu = 0;
while ($rows = mysql_fetch_array($searc)) {
$soma_das_visu += $rows['algo']; 
}
?>
```

Comment: Assim não vai somar nada, só vai saber o resultado do último elemento.

Comment: @Jorge B. Realmente Jorge. Editei o poste, pois passei despercebido no array_sum.

Comment: a resposta do @perdeu ;)

Comment: Obrigado Lucas e Jorge. It's done!