# Como calcular média de um resultado de query mysql?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Como faço para pegar o campo "count(t2.id_atend) TOTAL_ATENDIMENTO
" e calcular a media dele no PHP?

```
SELECT t3.desc_serv, 
    t3.nm_serv,
    t1.nm_usu,
    count(t2.id_atend) TOTAL_ATENDIMENTO
FROM usuarios t1
INNER JOIN historico_atendimentos t2 ON t1.id_usu = t2.id_usu
INNER JOIN servicos t3 ON t2.id_serv = t3.id_serv
WHERE t3.id_serv = 9 AND t2.dt_fim LIKE '%2013-10%'
GROUP BY t3.id_serv, t1.id_usu
```

print do resultado:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: No sql pões `count(t2.id_atend) as total`, depois é só pegar o total como pegas os outros elementos. Para saber o número de registos é só contar o número de resultados obtidos pela query que fizeste.

Comment: Não entendi meu caro.

Comment: Tu sabes ir buscar os valores de t3.nm_serv e t1.nm_usu, certo?

Comment: $res = count($resulta); 
Fiz a contagem de registros, mas preciso fazer a soma deles, mas essa soma faço no php ou no sql mesmo?

Comment: Vê [esta pergunta](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/14404/7210) acho que se enquadra e tens ai as duas formas de o fazer nas respostas.

Answer (score 2):

```
select avg(TOTAL_ATENDIMENTO) MEDIA_TOTAL_ATENDIMENTO
from
(
SELECT t3.desc_serv, 
    t3.nm_serv,
    t1.nm_usu,
    count(t2.id_atend) TOTAL_ATENDIMENTO
FROM usuarios t1
INNER JOIN historico_atendimentos t2 ON t1.id_usu = t2.id_usu
INNER JOIN servicos t3 ON t2.id_serv = t3.id_serv
WHERE t3.id_serv = 9 AND t2.dt_fim LIKE '%2013-10%'
GROUP BY t3.id_serv, t1.id_usu
) virtual
```